# Get Substring from Url

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0

I have some Urls string, such as:

http://www.testproject.com/tokyo/4 
http://www.testproject.com/india/11 
http://www.testproject.com/singapore/819

How to get the number ("4". "11", "819") in the end of Url?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The other answers using string methods would be correct if this was a simple string, but since this is a URL, you should use the proper class to handle URIs:

```
var url = new Uri("http://www.testproject.com/tokyo/4");
var lastSegment = url.Segments.Last();
```

Comment: That's very true, nice one :)

Comment: Can you list any corner case which this solution would handle correctly and AD.Net's answer would not? If there's no such case, his method would execute faster, no?

Comment: @dotNet If performance was the only issue, then yes the LastIndexOf would be 'faster'. But what if the URL contained a query or fragment? Or what if the desired segment wasn't always last but second from last? Using the proper parser enables a lot more flexibility.

Comment: @dotNet and AndrewHanlon the downside of your perfect answer is that the programmer is reduced to a typist with an extensive memory of MSDN reference material, whereas the string manipulation methods actually protect the programmer from one day becoming obsolete. Your perfect answer only needs speech recognition software to make the programmer unemployed. Think about that when you rush to high level functions. That day is steadily approaching. (;-D)

Comment: @dotNet ever wonder why German automobile engineers don't make their designs as simple as possible? it's called self-preservation!

Comment: @Sam: I see your point too, but then why do we live in a .NET world, or even C++? These built-in method just make you better concentrate on the application logic instead of reinventing the stupid little algorithm one billionth time. And it is that application logic for which a programmer, and not a speech engine, will always be required.

Answer (score 3):

Without using regex, you can find the index of last "/" by using `string.LastIndexOf('/')` and get the rest by using `string.SubString`

Answer (score 2):

Example of what AD.Net meant:

```
public string getLastBit(string s) {
    int pos = s.LastIndexOf('/') + 1;
    return s.Substring(pos, s.Length - pos);
}
```

Returns:

```
4, 11, 819
```

When passed in an individual url.

Answer (score 0):

```
string myUrl = "http://www.testproject.com/tokyo/4";

string[] parts = myUrl.Split('/');

string itIsFour = parts[parts.Length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int LastFwdSlash = URLString.LastIndexOf('/');
String Number = URLString.Substring(LastFwdSlash + 1, URLString.Length);
int Number = int.Parse(URLString);
```